# Cardinality of un-symmetric subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let's call a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is bounded **bad** if the only symmetry it has is the identity, i.e it cannot be rotated or reflected in any way that gets back to the original other than doing nothing. Then two natural questions arise:

1. What is the cardinality of all non-congruent bad sets?
2. What is the cardinality of all non-similar bad sets?

I'm not sure how to find either of these - but just from intuition I except the answer to be greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: By a symmetry, I mean a distance preserving bijection from the subset to itself (with the usual distance metric)

Comment: @amWhy I should be more precise to bypass all of these, by instead of saying a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ saying a Jordan Curve. Then congruency and similarity are pretty standard definitions - no? Congruent means literally the same thing, just translated and rotated and similarity is congruent but with scaling.

Comment: @amWhy I've edited the question. Please make edits yourself if you know what I'm trying to say but something needs to be clarified or expanded on, or just tell me.

Comment: @JairTaylor Done, thank you.

Comment: You just need a way to construct lots of sets with no symmetries.  For example, take some shape with no symmetries, like a scalene triangle, and consider all the sets consisting of this triangle and a subset of the interior.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for both questions is $2^{|\mathbb R|}$. Consider the set of sets of the form $$\{(0,0)\}\cup A\cup \{(2,0)\},$$ 
where $A$ is any nonempty subset of the open line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. These sets all have a diameter of 2, so they are similar iff they are congruent. With some thought, these sets are pairwise non-congruent. Since there are $2^{|\mathbb R|}$ choices for $A$, we are done.

Comment: This construction proves that the cardinality is at least 2^R, but I don’t see how it shows that there can’t be tons of other families of bad sets that raise the cardinality further.

Comment: Also, wouldn’t such a line have reflectional and rotational (180°) symmetries and therefore not be bad?

Comment: For your second comment, see my edit. I made a mistake; A was only supposed to be present in the left half of the segment from (0,0) to (2,0). To your first comment: the cardinality of _all_ subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ is $2^{|\mathbb R^2|}=2^{|\mathbb R|}$, so the cardinality of bad subsets  cannot get be greater than this.